# How to know what is my touchpad device to enable multitouch and advanced gestures?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad

Right now, it only works the right and left click, and the scroll at the right part of the touchpad. Windows 7 detects it as a mouse with scroll wheel. I tried the latest Synaptics drivers and some other Synaptics drivers. But advanced and multitouch options don't appear anywhere. This is a generic Chinese ultrabook.

Is it because it is not a Synaptics touchpad?

This is the Everest report with the Synaptics driver:

```
Descripción del controlador     Synaptics PS/2 Port TouchPad
Fecha del controlador           25/02/2013
Versión del controlador         16.3.15.1
Proveedor del controlador       Synaptics
Archivo INF                     oem9.inf
Identificación del hardware     ACPI\PNP0F03
Dispositivo PnP                 Microsoft PS/2 Port Mous
```

This is the Everest report with the generic Microsoft driver:

```
Descripción del controlador     Mouse PS/2 de Microsoft
Fecha del controlador           21/06/2006
Versión del controlador         6.1.7600.16385
Proveedor del controlador       Microsoft
Archivo INF                     msmouse.inf
Identificación del hardware     ACPI\PNP0F03
Dispositivo PnP                 Microsoft PS/2 Port Mouse
```

This is a screenshot of the Synaptics utility to change the advanced features (advanced features are not shown!):

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

First access your mouse properties. In Windows 7 right click the desktop>properties>change mouse pointers and then look for something like this:

[image: 1]

If you can't find it the touch pad may not support it. Try looking for software for your touch pad.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately there isn't that option. Maybe I need another software for the touchpad, but I don't know where to look for it! :(

Comment: Try the manufacturer's website.